# Lombok excluding field with @ToString.Exclude is not working

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using Lombok to remove boilerplate code.  I'm attempting to print out an entity to the console but I'm getting a StackOverflowError.  The entity has a bidirectional relationship with another entity, so I want to exclude this entity from the toString method.

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long fooId;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "barId")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Bar bar; 
}
```

This is my first time attempting to use `@ToString.Exclude` and it doesn't appear to be behaving.  Am I using it incorrectly? I just want to print out `fooId` and `name` when I call toString on the Foo object.

**Edit**

I'm familiar with alternate approaches to excluding or including fields from a top level `@ToString` annotation.  I'm attempting to avoid that.  I just want to use `@Data` at the class level, and annotate the fields that should be excluded.

**Edit 2**

Still replicating on a simplified class.  Lombok version 1.18.8.

[image]

Comment: Check this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649564/include-into-lombok-tostring-field-from-another-object

Comment: I don't think `@ToString.Exclude` works independent of `@ToString`. Going through the documentation to check. https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/ToString.html

Comment: @SubirKumarSao thanks for the reply.  Replacing `@Data` with `@ToString` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: The version (1.16) we are using works with @ToString(exclude="bar")

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDagger `@Data` includes `@ToString` so you are good at that part.

Comment: @Jayr, that works for me as well.  I recently learned about `@ToString.Exclude` and I would like to use that as an alternative.

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDagger Strip the ORM annotations and check the imports are correct. Lets debug from there. Post the `toString()` output.

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDagger, did you find a solution? Facing same problem.

Comment: Is there any other way to exclude field from printing data in toString method withou Lombok or any other framework?

Answer (score 33):

Works for me. `lombok:1.18.8`

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Data
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        System.out.println("ToString::" + myClass);
    }

    private String a = "ABC";

    @ToString.Exclude
    private String b = "DEF";

}
```

Output: `ToString::MyClass(a=ABC)`

Comment: Thanks for posting and +1.  I was on 1.18.6 but the issue still remains when I upgrade.  I removed all the JPA annotations and the issue still remains. Hmmm....

Comment: Did you update both the eclipse Lombok plugin and the project dependency, and clean/rebuild the project?

Answer (score 7):

`@ToString` takes an argument `exclude`, that can be used to exclude fields from to string.

`@ToString(exclude = {"bar"})`

```java
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = {"bar"})
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long fooId;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "barId")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Bar bar; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to update the lombok installed in your eclipse (download the new lombok.jar, run `java -jar lombok.jar` and restart Eclipse). At least that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
lombok : 1.18.12
```

@Exclude works for me. @Exclude is nothing but @ToString.Exclude only. @Exclude annotation is defined inside @ToString annotation.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long fooId;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "barId")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Exclude
    private Bar bar; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### In Kotlin

You could avoid using the Lombok library and define a custom annotation [`@ExcludeToString`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63108202/5279996) to exclude the redundant parameter or what you need.

GL