# StackOverflowError Springboot OneToMany BiDirectional Mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, lombok, many-to-one

I am currently coding a project, which requires me to map in between two entities: An account and a member. An account can have multiple members, whilst the member can only have one account. 
After I've finished coding the bidirectional way, everything was working and I got the response I wanted, which is the members only.

From here on the problems started:
I started coding my way to "recipe". Recipe is connected in a ManyToOne relationship to "house", which then has a 1:1 relationship to "account". After implementing this, I've discovered a StackOverFlow, which previously wasn't there. (The one between Account and Member)

Below is an image of said structure in the database. Recipe -> House -> Account.
(The relationships and tables, with blue crosses on top exist, but aren't really connected)
[image: The ERM]

My entities look like this:

```
package com.myhome.api.components.account.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.myhome.api.components.house.entity.House;
import com.myhome.api.components.member.entity.Member;
import com.myhome.api.components.recipe.entity.Recipe;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Table(name = "account")
@Entity
@Data
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "token")
    private String token;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "fkAccountId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Member> members;
}
```

```
package com.myhome.api.components.member.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.myhome.api.components.account.entity.Account;
import com.myhome.api.components.meal.entity.Meal;
import com.myhome.api.components.rating.entity.Rating;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Table(name = "member")
@Entity
@Data
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "icon")
    private Integer icon;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fkAccountId", nullable = false)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Account fkAccountId;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "fkMemberId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Meal> meals;

    @OneToMany(
            cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true,
            mappedBy = "fkMemberId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Rating> ratings;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why is this happening, even tho it didn't happen before I added the connection in between recipe and house?
2. How can I fix it?
3. What are the causes?

Comment: Don't use `@Data` for entities, it is a bad idea. It generates bad, `hashCode`, `equals` and `toString` methods, leading to all sorts of issues. One of those is the one you encountered now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this happening

This is caused by `toString()` method being present in both the classes and forming cyclic dependency. This leads to infinite recursion calls between `Account` and `Member`'s  toString() methods.

Consider these 2 simple classes. Lombok's `@Data` generates toString method for all fields by default.

```
class Member {
    String name;
    Account account;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", account=" + account.toString() + //Although string concatenation calls toString() on instance, I thought of adding it to call it out
                '}';
    }
}

class Account {
    String id;
    Member member;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", member=" + member.toString() + //Although string concatenation calls toString on instance, I thought of adding it to call it out
                '}';
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account account = new Account();
        Member member  = new Member();
        account.id="1";
        account.member=member;

        member.name ="XYZ";
        member.account=account;

        System.out.println(account);
    }
```

When you call toString method on one of the classes, say `Account` it will in turn call `toString` method of `Member` and the cycle repeats until you run out of stack memory. Here's the stacktracee:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at com.javainuse.main.Member.toString(AnotherMain.java:23)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.javainuse.main.Account.toString(AnotherMain.java:10)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

> How can I fix it?

Exclude toString generation for one of the classes from your lombok and that should work.[refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56263668/8283737) I would recommend not having toString at all for entity classes.

> What are the causes?

I don't think I understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What are the causes?
What I meant by this is: Why are "hashcode, tostring & equals" methods bad and why don't they work together with spring?

Comment: That's a big topic in itself. You can find more on the internet. But one I can think of right now is lazy loading gets triggered even if you aren't really asking for it.